# How to implement "where" (numpy.where(...) )?

Tags: python, scala, haskell, functional-programming, numpy

I'm a functional programming newbie.
I'd like to know how to implement numpy.where() in python, scala or haskell.
A good explanation would be helpful to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Haskell, doing it for n-dimensional lists, as the NumPy equivalent supports, requires a fairly advanced typeclass construction, but the 1-dimensional case is easy:

```hs
select :: [Bool] -> [a] -> [a] -> [a]
select [] [] [] = []
select (True:bs) (x:xs) (_:ys) = x : select bs xs ys
select (False:bs) (_:xs) (y:ys) = y : select bs xs ys
```

This is just a simple recursive procedure, examining each element of each list in turn, and producing the empty list when every list reaches its end. (Note that these are lists, not arrays.)

Here's a simpler but less obvious implementation for 1-dimensional lists, translating the definition in the NumPy documentation (credit to joaquin for pointing it out):

```hs
select :: [Bool] -> [a] -> [a] -> [a]
select bs xs ys = zipWith3 select' bs xs ys
  where select' True x _ = x
        select' False _ y = y
```

To achieve the two-argument case (returning all indices where the condition is True; credit to Rex Kerr for pointing this case out), a list comprehension can be used:

```hs
trueIndices :: [Bool] -> [Int]
trueIndices bs = [i | (i,True) <- zip [0..] bs]
```

It could also be written with the existing `select`, although there's not much point:

```hs
trueIndices :: [Bool] -> [Int]
trueIndices bs = catMaybes $ select bs (map Just [0..]) (repeat Nothing)
```

And here's the three-argument version for n-dimensional lists:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses, FlexibleInstances #-}

class Select bs as where
  select :: bs -> as -> as -> as

instance Select Bool a where
  select True x _ = x
  select False _ y = y

instance (Select bs as) => Select [bs] [as] where
  select = zipWith3 select
```

Here's an example:

```hs
GHCi> select [[True, False], [False, True]] [[0,1],[2,3]] [[4,5],[6,7]]
[[0,5],[6,3]]
```

You would probably want to use a proper n-dimensional array type instead in practice, though. If you just want to use `select` on an n-dimensional list for one specific *n*, luqui's advice (from the comments of this answer) is preferable:

> In practice, instead of the typeclass hack, I would use `(zipWith3.zipWith3.zipWith3) select' bs xs ys` (for the three dimensional case).

(adding more compositions of `zipWith3` as *n* increases.)

Comment: In practice, instead of the typeclass hack, I would use `(zipWith3.zipWith3.zipWith3) select' bs xs ys` (for the three dimensional case).  If I don't know the number of dimensions when I am writing, then, as you said, I would use a proper abstract type.

Comment: Yes, I completely. Still, if you really want to implement `numpy.where` in Haskell... Thanks for making me that `zipWith3` would work here, by the way! I've edited my answer accordingly, and included your comment. :)

Answer (score 5):

In python from `numpy.where.__doc__`:

```
If `x` and `y` are given and input arrays are 1-D, `where` is
equivalent to::

    [xv if c else yv for (c,xv,yv) in zip(condition,x,y)]
```

Answer (score 3):

There are two use cases for where; in one case, you have two arrays, and in the other, you only have one.

In the two-item case, `numpy.where(cond)`, you get a list of indices where the condition-array is true.  In Scala, you would normally

```
(cond, cond.indices).zipped.filter((c,_) => c)._2
```

which obviously is less compact, but this isn't a fundamental operation that people normally use in Scala (the building blocks are different, de-emphasizing indices, for example).

In the three-item case, `numpy.where(cond,x,y)`, you get either `x` or `y` depending on whether `cond` is true (`x`) or false (`y`).  In Scala,

```
(cond, x, y).zipped.map((c,tx,ty) => if (c) tx else ty)
```

performs the same operation (again less compact, but again, not typically a fundamental operation).  Note that in Scala you can more easily have `cond` be a method that tests `x` and `y` and produces true or false, and then you would

```
(x, y).zipped.map((tx,ty) => if (c(tx,ty)) tx else ty)
```

(although typically even when being brief you'd name the arrays `xs` and `ys` and the individual elements `x` and `y`).